# If I upgrade my OS will CS4 still work?

Tags: macos, adobe

I have Adobe Creative Suite 4 running on OS 10.5.8.

If I upgrade to 10.6.6 will CS4 programs still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have it running on Lion ( 10.7.2 )

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop CS4 is running fine for me under OS X 10.6.8.

NOTE, for switching the OS it is safest to go into the Help menu to deactivate Photoshop, then activate again the first time you use it after switching.

Comment: Safest, meaning what? Does this have to do with the software licensing? (I don't have CS4; just curious what this really means.)

Comment: You are allowed two (I think) copies installed at a time.  Uninstall one to install another.  But under some circumstances (I don't know the details) the new OS may be seen as a new installation.